# How to get the number of a line that matches a specific text in a file

Tags: vbscript

does someone know by the use of vbs the way to get the line number that matches a specific text in a file. (the text is send as a parameter). As example, i'd like to be able to say this text is on line eleven.

Please, don't take account that the text occurs more than once in file.

Thank for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping over the lines of an TextStream, its .Line property

> Read-only property that returns the current line number in a
>   TextStream file.

holds the desired info.

Comment: thanks. But is there no way to go once on searching line without need to loop over each line of file? Thanks more...